# Iterate object until find the value matching with lable

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular8

In my angular project, I am manipulating the table by dynamic. when i do this i am getting a challenge in the data node. the values are directly available it works fine.

Sometime the values under the object or children of the object. so I need iterate the data until if there is a value match. if there is no value let it be empty.

how to do this?

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  columns = [{
    title:"NAME",
    data:"name"
  },
  {
    title:"CITY",
    data:"city"
  }];

  datas = [
    {
      name:"US",
      city:"Newyork"
    },
     {
       name:"Japan",
       parent: {
         first: {
           city:"Tokyo"
         }
       }
    },
     {
      name:"UK",
      parent: {
        city:"London"
      }
    }
  ];

  getData(data, label) {
    if(!data[label]) {
      console.log(data, label) //how to do all the way with data?
    }
    return data[label]
  }
}


HTML:

<table>
  <tbody>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">{{col.title}}</th>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of datas">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{getData(data, col.data)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-table-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse `this.datas` in required format, so that you can use it in `for` loop.

the below function `getCity()` recursively loops and finds city value.

```js
 function getCity(obj) {
 if(obj.city) {
  return obj.city;
 }
 for(var x in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[x] === 'object') {
   return this.getCity(obj[x]);
  }
 }
  return 'not found';
  }
  
  var obj1 = {
      name:"UK",
      parent: {
        city:"London"
      }
    }
    
 var obj2 = {
       name:"Japan",
       parent: {
         first: {
           city:"Tokyo"
         }
       }
    }
  console.log(getCity(obj1));
  console.log(getCity(obj2));
    console.log(getCity({}));
```

So on `ngOnInit()` lifecycle method parse `this.datas`.

You can find the above changes here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enwpsn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts`

Comment: Bharath, still you solution works when I know the data requirement. My app is maintained by cms. so I don't know the data value. even in future the column value could be updated as dynamic. so server will decide. - this is to know the context of the requirement

Comment: make `getCity()` generic so that is can return values for dynamic keys